# calling execute() function inside rows.map() function in node js

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I have list of users which is fetched from below code

```
const q = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE tenant = ?'
  cassandra.execute(q, [tnid], (err, r) => {
    if (err) return res.end500(err)
    const u = r.rows.map(cred)
    const data = { users: u }
    res.end200(data)
  })
```

inside map() I am calling cred() as below

```
function cred(src)
{
 var data=src
 async.series([
    function(callback){
         hashs(src.name.full_name, callback)
    }
    ],
   function(err,res) {
      console.log("------res--------")
      if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          callback()
      }
      data.hash=res
      console.log(data)
      return data
     })
}
```

which async calls hashs() function to fetch hash value required for specific user

```
function hashs(un,callback) {
  const q = SELECT hash FROM user_credentials WHERE username = ?
   cassandra.execute(q, un, (err, r) => {
    if (err) return err
    console.log(r.rows)
    callback(null,r.rows[0])
  })
callback(null,un)
}
```

But main issue is that once I get user details, 2nd query is not fired to fetch hash value and so I am not getting hash value from 2nd table.

This is same concept named as JOIN in SQL but I am using Cassandra which is based on nosql, so I am not able to fetch all details of specific user in single query.

Basically I am not able to call `cassandra.execute()` inside `map()`

Comment: You say, cannot call `cassandra.execute()` inside `map()`. Is this because of an error (then what is reported) or because it doesn't return the expected data? Can you please provide the logged output from your console?

Comment: I have got user details from **user** table as expected in log but I require column name **hash** from another table named **user_credentials** matching on common field i.e. **username**

Comment: The problem might be that you give the username to `execute()` as a string, but it should be in an array. Try `cassandra.execute(q, [un], (err, r) => { ... }` and log output in the error case as well (currently you `return err` but then discard it silently.

Comment: I have tried `[un]` as well but I don't get data from **user_credentials**. Basically I am not getting data from another table when 1st execution is going on.